# Como pintar una fecha que viene de una tabla Sql en un calendario en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo un calendario, en el cual estoy coloreando los días de descanso en color Naranja, en base a la fecha de inicio de jornada del empleado y su Tipo de Jornada.
Lo que deseo hacer ahora, es traer una fecha (`FechaSalida`)desde mi base de datos, esta fecha me indica si trabajo en el día de descanso que le tocaba, y si trabajo marcar el día en color amarillo y no en naranja, como puedo lograrlo?

```
private void calFecha_DayRender(object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)  //Colores en Calendario
        {
            bool final = true;
            if (ddloperadores.SelectedValue != "Todos")
            {                
                DataTable asistencia = OperadoresBL.OperadoresForaneosAsistencia((int)WAPS.Globals.ConvertTo(txtNumOperador.Text, 0)).Tables[0];    //Datos de Store                    

                if (asistencia.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow iRow = asistencia.Rows[0];
                    string Tipo = iRow["TipoJornada"].ToString();

                    DateTime FechaJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Ini"]);

                    if (Tipo == "1") //Tipos de Jornadas
                    {
                        if (FechaJornada <= e.Day.Date)
                        {                                  
                            int rem = (e.Day.Date - FechaJornada).Days % 10; //Total de días 

                                DateTime FechaSalida = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["FechaSalida"]);
                                if (rem >= 0 && rem <= 7) //Días Laborales                                      
                                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;        
                                else //días de descanso obligatorios
                                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;                       
                        }
                        else                          
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;                        

                        }
                 }
          }
}
```

Código Actual con el foreach

```
private void calFecha_DayRender(object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)  //Colores en Calendario
        {
            bool final = true;
            if (ddloperadores.SelectedValue != "Todos")
            {                
                DataTable asistencia = OperadoresBL.OperadoresForaneosAsistencia((int)WAPS.Globals.ConvertTo(txtNumOperador.Text, 0)).Tables[0];    //Datos de Store 
                if (asistencia.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow iRow = asistencia.Rows[0];
                    string Tipo = iRow["TipoJornada"].ToString();                      
                    DateTime FechaJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Ini"]);

                    if (Tipo == "1") //Tipos de Jornadas
                    {                         
                        if (FechaJornada <= e.Day.Date)
                        {                                
                            int rem = (e.Day.Date - FechaJornada).Days % 10; //Total de días 

                                if (rem >= 0 && rem <= 7) //Días Laborales  
                                {
                                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    foreach (DataRow row in asistencia.Rows)
                                    {
                                        DateTime FechaSalida = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["FechaSalida"]);
                                        if (e.Day.Date == FechaSalida.Date) 
                                        {
                                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;                                                
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        }


                    }
              }
        }
  }
```

Con esto me muestra solo una fecha pero me faltan las otras 2 fechas que mi FechaSalida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITADO

Por si esto puede valer para alguien mas quito tantas ediciones y pongo el codigo final:

```
private void calFecha_DayRender(object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)  //Colores en Calendario
    {
        bool final = true;
        if (ddloperadores.SelectedValue != "Todos")
        {                
            DataTable asistencia = OperadoresBL.OperadoresForaneosAsistencia((int)WAPS.Globals.ConvertTo(txtNumOperador.Text, 0)).Tables[0];    //Datos de Store 
            if (asistencia.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow iRow = asistencia.Rows[0];
                string Tipo = iRow["TipoJornada"].ToString();                      
                DateTime FechaJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Ini"]);

                if (Tipo == "1") //Tipos de Jornadas
                {                         
                    if (FechaJornada <= e.Day.Date)
                    {                                
                        int rem = (e.Day.Date - FechaJornada).Days % 10; //Total de días 

                            if (rem >= 0 && rem <= 7) //Días Laborales  
                            {
                                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                foreach (DataRow row in asistencia.Rows)
                                {
                                    DateTime FechaSalida = Convert.ToDateTime(row["FechaSalida"]);
                                    if (e.Day.Date == FechaSalida.Date) 
                                    {
                                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                                        return;                                                
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                                    }
                                }
                            }                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    }


                }
          }
    }
```

}

Comment: muchas gracias Gerardo, si esto era lo que quería mostrar, solo en el if en lugar de Daty coloque day me da color amarillo en el día de descanso que tengo en FechaSalida. En mi FechaSalida no solo tengo una fecha si no que tengo 3 fechas más como puedo hacer para que esas tres fechas se puedan marcar de color también. @Gerardo

Comment: ¿Que es FechaSalida una List, un array?

Comment: es una List, no es un array.

Comment: Pues tendrías que mirar si la fecha que estas consultando existen en la lista. Edito la respuesta

Comment: pues lo intente con List pero me marca error no me deja declarar la fila de FechaSalida.Add yo estaba tratando de hacerlo sin List directo de datatable que tengo de Asistencia y colocando un foreach (DataRow Row in asistencia.Rows){ y la condición que me diste en un inicio, pero no lo logro con mi foreach no me marca error pero no me regresa las otras 2 fechas solo me regresa una :S

Comment: Podrías poner el código para ver exactamente como lo haces ?

Comment: si claro lo agrego abajo de mi pregunta, con leyenda de Código Actual Foreach

Comment: Ok ya vi el error te lo comento en la respuesta editada en el parte FOREACH. Un saludo.

Comment: listo he quitado la i dejando solo Row, funciona pero ahora solo me regresa la ultima FechaSalida, antes era la primera y sigue sin mostrarme las otras 2 fechas me faltara algo más

Comment: he estado modificado mi foreach pero me continua mostrando solo la ultima fecha en color amarillo, sin lograr que los demás se coloquen en color amarillo :s

Comment: Ok fallo mio hay q salir del foreach cuando encuentras la fecha. Bastaría con poner un break o un return.

Comment: lo he colocado y me funciona de forma correcta, muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Gerardo , que tengas buen inicio de semana.